# phantomjs cannot find module webpage in node's child process

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I'm trying to run phantomjs in a node child process. Phantomjs complains it can not find module 'webpage'. Running the script from the cli works fine:

```
phantomjs script.js
```

I stripped the problem down to these two files:

main.js:

```
var script = require('./script');
var cp = require('child_process');
cp.exec('/usr/bin/phantomjs script.js');
```

script.js

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open("http://www.google.com", function(status) {
  console.log("opened google? ", status);
  var title = page.evaluate(function(s) {
    return s;
  }, 'Hello');
  console.log(title);
  phantom.exit();
 });
```

Running the following command fails:

```
node main.js
```

with error:

```
module.js:340
   throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'webpage'
```

I've tried to specify the working directory in cp.exec as an option without effect. Is there a way to set the node search path for modules in a global context so it can be found in a new node process? Or am I doing something else wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhantomJS is not a node.js module and cannot be directly used from node. I think you understand this, because you try to invoke it via `child_process`.

The problem is the line `var script = require('./script');`. As I understand, it is the phantomjs script. Since node.js doesn't have a `webpage` module, but phantomjs does the require fails and everything with it. Simply remove the line. It doesn't seem like you use it anyway.